# Carrying out tests which would give a degree

Tags: exams, degree, online-learning, online-degree

With the Internet having more and more data every day, a lot of which is science-related, a kind of test could be used to give a degree for someone who knows a lot.

The questions of the test would be graduate level of difficulty. Can this become applicable in the near future or not?

For example, someone who has passion about a topic and has studied online would be given the chance to get a degree. Now, of course, at a university there are labs and this wont be applicable for every profession but since most software used by universities to teach are available for everyone, I don't know maybe if someone  completed a course or something he would get a graduate degree.

Comment: If you can PROVE that you understand the same stuff to someone with a degree , I dont get why you shouldnt be rewarded.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to obtain a bachelor's degree by passing some test to prove equivalent knowledge rather than attending a university?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/74810) and [Why not offer credit by exam to students who have failed a course?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/173702)

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Your question is interesting, but just a caution that it is our role to explain how things work in the real academic world, and why. So if your goal is to understand how things work and why, that's great, welcome aboard. But if your goal is to convince us that things should work differently, that's not really what we do here.

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!.I am not trying to convince anyone.I want to have a conversation on the topic.Quote:"Can this become applicable in the near future or not?"

Comment: @Cerise Stack Exchange works differently from forum sites or Reddit. See in particular https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask "*If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.*" We're looking for specific, answerable questions, not discussions and conversations.

Comment: Bryan's comment was my feeling as well, but a few others had answered it. I think if it was rephrased as something like "what are the hurdles and limitations to online tests of knowledge and skill becoming as an equivalent alternative to university degrees in the near future?" then it would be an appropriate question

Comment: I voted to close, but also cleaned up your English. Please note that a space follows punctuation in English. It makes your comments very difficult to read to not follow this convention.

Comment: On retrospect, I think this should be closed as a dupe of cag's first question, but I can't change my vote (I think "graduate degree" here is a bad translation).

Comment: There are some shady on-line universities (so-called) that offer degrees to those who pay the fees and pass the tests.  (Probably merely paying the fees without taking the tests at all is also possible...)

Answer (score 3):

> With the Internet having more and more data every day,many of which are science related a kind of test could be used to give a degree for someone who knows very much.The questions of the test would be graduate level of difficulty.

You are misunderstanding the fact that being awarded a PhD degree does not hinge on a test of knowledge, but rather on a test of ability, namely the ability to produce novel and meaningful scientific research. There might be some tests of knowledge involved on the way towards a PhD (qualifying exams and such), but it fundamentally is not a test of knowledge. A PhD is not, contrary to popular impression, a certification that you are a smart and knowledgeable person.

It does not matter in the slightest that you answer super-tough questions about a given field if you have not demonstrated that you can actually contribute to research in that field.

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!A PhD is a very different monster to a graduate's degree.

Comment: @Cerise A PhD is a type of graduate degree (note: not "graduate's degree"). If you are talking specifically about Master's degrees or something like a JD, you should specify that in your question, in which case I will delete my answer. As it stands, it's not exactly clear to me what kind of degree you have in mind.

Comment: Because the PhD is a subset of a graduate's degree you cant assume Im referring to a PhD but its fine no I am not referring to a PhD or a Master's degree.

Comment: So what *are* you referring to when you are referring to a graduate degree which is neither a Master's degree nor a PhD? Granted, other kinds of graduate degrees exist, but those are certainly the two main kinds of graduate degrees, so it's rather misleading to ask a question about graduate degrees and then say that you're not referring to a PhD or a Master's degree.

Comment: The degree below Master's.

Comment: @Cerise That would be a bachelor's degree, presumably. That's not a graduate degree. I genuinely don't understand what this mystery graduate degree which is not a Master's or a PhD but it's "below Master's" but it's still a graduate degree is supposed to be.

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Accreditation is the process by which educational institutions are evaluated to make sure they meet certain standards. Getting a certificate saying you passed some online test has little value without understanding who's giving the certificate and what the accomplishment represents. I'm sure you can find an online test that says you're a genius, why should anyone believe it?

It is of course possible to take tests from an accredited online institution and receive a degree, that's the usual route of online study.  It is also possible to take tests from a non-accredited institution and receive some kind of certificate saying you did it, although that has comparatively little value depending on who's giving the certificate. You generally cannot simply take one test from an accredited institution and receive a degree, as an institution that handed out degrees in that manner would almost certainly not meet accreditation requirements.

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!Obviously the course will come from a credited institution

Comment: @Cerise There's your problem. Degrees awarded by accredited institutions carry implications about the time spent and mastery achieved in the program. Passing an online test doesn't say much about the standards. Getting a degree from a medical school is understood to mean something, passing a test on anatomy.com is not. If you are talking about getting a degree from an accredited online institution, then you can of course do that, but it's not simply a case of passing a test.

Comment: And conversely, even if there were an institution out there that figured out a way to test you, that institution would still have to get accredited for others to pay attention to it. One can assume that they will have a hard time getting that accreditation from an accreditation bureau that is widely trusted.

Answer (score 0):

While (barely) possible this seems unlikely, especially in a time frame that would be useful to you. You would need to find a university, hopefully a reputable one, willing to do it as well as a problem significant enough to have the faculty there agree that you had covered  all the necessary bases.

It is also unlikely that very many people would be able to gain the necessary knowledge both about the field and about research to make this common enough that people would consider it. One of the problems is that you can learn on your own but focused learning usually (i.e. most people) requires guidance. That is what graduate, especially doctoral programs, are all about: both the what and the how of contributions to scholarship.

Some people have been awarded honorary degrees, which don't carry quite the same weight, for their work outside academia that contributes something important, or even a lifetime of contributions.

See the [canonical question about doctoral admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368) to see what is usually required before you are even allowed to begin doctoral study.

It is a lot more than being about being "smart" or "knowing a lot" of stuff.

But it is rare because so few could begin to do it, so it hasn't been considered enough to be an option in almost every case. And it is also unlikely that you could get a degree for some "exam", though exams are often required in doctoral study to guarantee broad knowledge of a field.

---

I suspect that if it were to become more common, it would require a process in which one first makes a plan and a proposal, then gets approval (or not), and then executes the plan and carries out the study. The approval process might be quite difficult.

The reputation of universities depends in part on doing things right which implies some vetting process. This would be especially true in some fields where human subjects are involved.

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!What if someone cannot afford university expenses but he/she is really good at science and passionate about it.The scholarships given by universities after high school only fill a water droplet in the  bucket  of the talented people.

Comment: "It is a lot more than being about being "smart" or "knowing a lot" of stuff."Hmm 200 years ago this was how the scientific community was working.Gauss enrolled in a university at the age of 12,Faraday was a librarian assistant.

Comment: Then all you need is a time machine ;-) And, even then, it was rare. Maybe especially then.

Comment: Note that it is also the people who are "really good at science" that get those scholarships. The world is what it is, imperfect as it is.

Comment: I wouldn't want a doctor or an engineer that approached there work like it was done 200 years ago. At that time there was a lot fewer academics, and science was smaller and less specialised. With modern science you need different social structures to help organise the work efficiently. If your focus is on inability to afford university expenses then it would be better to change society so everyone could afford to attend university (be it money or time) rather than trying for a band-aid solution of an online test.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with just a test. The first one is that in my undergraduate degree I probably did at least 30-40 hours of exams (probably in excess of 50 hours). So you'd expect at least that much in the exam. Then this doesn't account for all the assignments, lab experiments, reports and other examination I went through. This means the exam would have to be essentially full time over 1 or 2 weeks minimum. This would also be expensive since you'd need a specialist to spend their time marking all these exams and you probably won't get the economy of scale that you get in normal university courses which reduces the marking time.

But what this doesn't capture is that not only is your education over years, but the testing was also done over years. You can always cram for an exam and then forget the stuff, but being able to remember the core material you learnt in each course, and then apply it in the next course done months or years later is a hidden test that is not as obvious when you look at undergraduate degrees. In addition by providing courses there is an additional guarantee than the student has been exposed to the connections between ideas as understood by experts. This is the guided learning that is provided by universities and is also a hidden factor that a degree signals. This understanding would also be something you'd want to probe if you were an accreditation giving institute.

So in reality you'd probably want a much longer period of testing (I'd guess on the order of 6-12 months, but wouldn't have to be full time) done by an intelligent agent that understands the field properly and can adjust the tests to make sure the random understanding obtained on the web actually sees all the connections. So I'd say, for this to be equal to a traditional degree, you'd probably need general AI as a precondition, at that point education is going to be very different.

This also says nothing about graduate degrees which rely on undergraduate understanding. For coursework components you could probably repeat the arguments I made for undergraduate, but the research component is a lot harder to test. This would probably require a kind of apprenticeship for the examination (like I mentioned in the last paragraph) as well as demonstration of the appropriate level of research skills, this is very different to just learning stuff off the web. But here we are kinda getting back into what we already have, just maybe on a cut down time scale.

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!Yes "But what this doesn't capture is that not only is your education over years, but the testing was also done over years. You can always cram for an exam and then forget the stuff, but being able to remember the core material you learnt in each course, and then apply it in the next course done months or years later is a hidden test that is not as obvious when you look at undergraduate degrees."This is a good argument.We mostly learn by constant exposure to a material there is even a quote:"Repetition is the mother of learning".But I dont agree with your second argument...

Comment: ...Yes the student inevitably is exposed to connections understood by experts but knowledge and news are spreading out faster than ever (due to the Internet) and there isnt a development in any field science , not posted somewhere in the Internet.

Comment: There are certain things that become folklore within fields (particularly experimental fields) which are not really posted on the internet, or are much harder to extract from other postings that only hint at them. But this second arguement is somewhat subtle, any test you take doesn't really test your knowledge, but rather suggests to me that you know the subject. If I was instructing you in something and then tested you I can make more assumptions about the value of your test results. If you come off the street and I test you, I need to be more thorough with the test for the same confidence.

Answer (score 0):

There are many other good answers, but one of the issues that underlies your question is really: *"What is a degree?"*

At its core, a degree is an institution such as a university saying "Yes, this person actually knows something". This works because those who are looking at the degree (employers) typically *trust* universities to have rigorous processes to actually verify the "actually knows something" part. But because there are so many universities in the world, and because not all of them are trustworthy, there is a second level of trust: Universities are "accredited" by accreditation agencies who check and verify that the universities that are accredited have rigorous processes when they certify  the "actually knows something" part. You see that degrees only really mean anything if the person who looks at a degree actually has trust that it means something. A degree from an unaccredited university does not inspire trust, and people will generally not accept such a degree as proof of "the person actually knows something".

In essence, what you are suggesting with the online test is that you want to set up "The Substitute University of the Internet", that can check from online posts, online tests, and other sources whether someone actually knows something -- and if so, give that person a degree, say the "Bachelor's Degree of Knowledge, awarded by The Substitute University of the Internet". You can of course do that. (That's perhaps a bit like Trump University.) The problem is that if those who present such a degree to a possible employer, these employers will generally disregard the degree unless they have trust in The Substitute University of the Internet, and at least at the moment people will generally not have that kind of trust. Of course, The Substitute University of the Internet could turn to one of the accreditation agencies for accreditation, and should it receive accreditation people will have trust -- but because, as the other answers point out, everyone believes that such tests can not be meaningfully done, one can suspect that the accreditation agencies will not accredit The Substitute University of the Internet, and so no trust is conferred.

The upshot is: Degrees, like money, are all about trust.

Comment: I never said anything about "University of the Internet" , I just said that the state with the help of a institution periodically to perform examination on someone's desired subject and if he passes , he will get a degree.

Answer (score -1):

Who would pay for the development of that test, and who would pay for the grading? As others have mentioned, such a test would be huge, and development and validation of that test will be expensive. Why would a university invest in that?

The grading will be a beast as well, why would a university agree that I spent that amount of Work-Time on non-tuition paying students?

In short, I suspect that the universities would have to ask such a high price for this test in order for it to be viable/profitable, that there just won't be enough demand for it.

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!Yes that is correct.But many people are introverts and have social anxiety so it may help them studying isolated.

Comment: All universities I worked at have support services available for people with anxieties. There are also legitimate distance universities that offer degree programmes, like the open university and the Fernuni Hagen.

Comment: @Cerise: This doesn't answer the question about who pays. There are for example also many handicapped people (disabled in body or mind) and yet, in most countries, adequate support is rare. Only because somebody would profil is not a reason enough for governments or companies to spend money.

Comment: @Cerise You can study solo in person too.

Comment: You cant study solo in person if there are questions being made in the class.You simply cannot ignore the noise.Have you tried it?

Comment: @Cerise Feeling disrupted by people asking questions in class is not introvertedness or social anxiety, that's something you should seek professional advice on because it isn't normal or healthy. Nevertheless, most studying occurs out of class